# one class for each string in list in python

Tags: python, class

Let's suppose I have a list of strings:

```
people = ['Mike','Paul','Caroline']
```

and a class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, is_married = False):
        self.name = name
        self.is_married =is_married
```

How can i iterate through the strings in the list, and for each string create an instance of Person?
Ideally, I would like to be able to call each instance through their name (the string), for example:

```
Mike.is_married = True
print(Mike.is_married)
```

Comment: _"Ideally, I would like to be able to call each instance through their name"_ No, no, you really don't want that. Store them in a dict instead and access them as `your_dict['Mike']`.

Comment: Because someone may have the name `print` and you'll take years to debug why doesn't your `print` command work.

Comment: Something like:    People_dict = {} \n
    for name in people: \n
        People_dict[name] = Person(name) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this creates a list of object dynamic

```
obj={}
for pers in people:
    obj[pers]=Person(pers)
print(obj)
```